# can obfs4 bridges bypass china firewall and turkey , iran's block?

Tags: obfs4

can obfs4 bridges bypass china firewall and turkey, iran's block? I know some bridges may not work in those countrys.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on usage case, but generally - yes. Obfs 3 and 4 are good when properly used - as all bridges you need to pay attention to elaborate the bridge key. But in such a countries you better use a private bridges, i.e. not published ones